# uninstalled kernel cannot boot anymore

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, bootable

So, basically I messed up I tried updating debian wheezy to debian jessie and at some point aptitude wanted to uninstall the kernel, I got a warning but I had faith and allowed it.

now I only have an old windows starter 7 on my eeepc with grub still in place.

How do I reinstall and upgrade debian ?
I think it went wrong because I mixed the debian sources with mint & other repositories.

thanks

Comment: You need to install a kernel that can boot debian, you don't need to reinstall the entire debian system. Mixing sources may not be a good idea, but it should not be a problem here, as far as you make sure you have a working kernel. The entire debian system is there, you just can't boot it because there is no kernel. I'd try getting a live CD (any GNU/Linux live CD for the same architecture should be ok. If you have a Jessie live CD, you can use it).  Then, if you don't have any kind of disk encryption, you could boot the live CD and chroot into debian and install a kernel using aptitude.

Comment: this eeepc does not have a cd reader, is there no way to repair the system with a tool using the windows 7(starter) ?

Comment: Do you have a pendrive and can the eeepc boot from USB pendrives? [ISOLINUX-based CDs can be easily converted to boot from USB pendrives](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/Isohybrid), and some live CDs are already prepared for that.

Comment: thanks, I succeeded in booting from a live usb, what do I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok soo I followed njsg suggestion to use a live usb

the I did this [How to restore a system after accidentally removing all kernels](https://askubuntu.com/a/166010/148249%20How%20to%20restore%20a%20system%20after%20accidentally%20removing%20all%20kernels?)

and used this https://wiki.debian.org/HowToUpgradeKernel

to find the available kernels

> apt-cache search linux-image

thanks a lot people